# Programmatically list variables in watch window

Tags: visual-studio, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

Is there a way to find out what variables are present in the watch window of visual studio?

```
DTE dte;
var watchWindow = dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindWatch);
```

We can get the watch window as above, but haven't found a way to get list of values in it.
I'm trying to get the variable names and the corresponding values.